# Minimum curvature path - implementation

Tags: matrices, optimization

I found a paper that describes how to find the shortest and minimum curvature path in a race track. I've already understood the steps on how to find the shortest path but can't figure out the minimum curvature path.

That is an abstract of the paper: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sR42.png

I don't understand eq. (12, 13, 14), what are [D] and [dx]?

I'm sorry for my  bad english, i hope someone can help me. I've read other question exactly like this one but no one could answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also had some trouble understanding this paper, but here is what I found about your question:

- $[\mathbf{D}]$ is calculated as follows:

From the third order polynomial, we can write: $\frac{d^2x_i}{dt^2}\bigm\lvert_{t=0}=2c_{i,x}$. Therefore,

$\frac{d^2\mathbf{\bar{x}}}{dt^2}\bigm\lvert_{t=0}=[\array{2c_{1,x} & \dots & 2c_{n,x}}]$

However, $c_{i,x}$ are all obtained with information of the points $\mathbf{\bar{x}}$. In fact, since we are talking about splines, there is a linear relationship between $c_{i,x}$ and $\mathbf{\bar{x}}$, i.e., $c_{i,x} = \mathbf{C}_{i,x}^T \mathbf{\bar{x}}$, where $\mathbf{C}_{i,x}$ is a column vector which depends on the type of spline. So,

$\frac{d^2\mathbf{\bar{x}}}{dt^2}\bigm\lvert_{t=0}=[\array{2\mathbf{C}_{1,x}^T \mathbf{\bar{x}} & \dots & 2\mathbf{C}_{n,x}^T\mathbf{\bar{x}} }] = 2 [\array{\mathbf{C}_{1,x}^T  & \dots & \mathbf{C}_{n,x}^T }] \mathbf{\bar{x}}$

Finally,

$\mathbf{D} = 2 [\array{\mathbf{C}_{1,x}^T  & \dots & \mathbf{C}_{n,x}^T }]$.

- $[\mathbf{dx}]$ is simply defined by:

$[\mathbf{dx}]=[\array{ (x_{l,1} - x_{r,1}) & \dots & (x_{l,n} - x_{r,n})}]$

This is a collection of vectors that tell the direction where the spline control points can move. In other words, they define the direction of the gray lines in the paper's Fig. 2.

OBS: The paper says it will minimize the curvature of the path, but as you can see, the derivative of Eq. (14) is taken only on $t = 0$, i.e., on the  control points. Therefore, it actually minimizes the curvature only on the control points. If you have enough control points, you might get a good minimum curvature path.